# Angular cli - ng command open the ng file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular project and if I want to start the project with 'ng serve' it is opening the ng file from

> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin

Also, I can start the project with 'npm start'.

Comment: which version you are using? for angular 2+ `ng new YourProjectName` to create a project and `ng serve` to run.

Comment: if you are able to run others commands such as ng new app, ng serve -o should work as well, what version of angular cli are you using ?

Comment: doesn't work any command with ng. The project is from github and I can only run with npm start.

Comment: you probably missing npm cli

Comment: 'npm' work. 

'ng' just open the ng file from that path. It not execute anything

Comment: @FilipLaurentiu I'm also getting the same issue. Did you resolve it already? thanks

Comment: Same problem here. NG calls try to open the file ng.js, located under \node_modules\@angular\cli\bin directory. Node and NPM are installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured wrong environment variable path.

Path should be:
`C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm`

NOTE: Verify `ng.cmd` file should be there in `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\npm`. If not please reinstall anglular cli.

Answer (score 24):

Remove path "C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin" from Environment variable - path. It worked for me.

Comment: When the path is removed NG is not recognized, when the path is added, it tries to open NG.JS file in angular-cli binaries path

Comment: Finally I can run ng command, your solution work for me.

Answer (score 9):

The problem was that I use ng in powershell. In cmd work..

Comment: o...m...g. This has taken 1 hour for me. Thanks for this comment. Why the hell isnt it working inside the powershell?

Comment: Similar problem here... I am unable to make it work in Visual Studio Code but it works fine in a gitbash terminal

Comment: Also works for me. This is the right solution in my case.

Comment: Why would this be the case?

Comment: holy cow ... this saved me! thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where typing **ng** in terminal open **ng.js** in vscode
so my fix to it in **Environment Variable** remove any angular path in system variable and in **user variable** add this path C:\Users\Here\AppData\Roaming\npm
don't forget to add your system name in the (Here)

Comment: When I open 'Edit the System Environment Variables' (<Windows key>, type 'environment'), I have details for two kinds of Environment Variables. The top one is User Variables, and the bottom is System Variables. I've clicked Edit on the item called 'Path' in my User Variables and added the file path, as per your solution. I never had anything similar in my System Variables. It still doesn't work for me. Is this as you described?

Comment: C:\Users\Zero\AppData\Roaming\npm did you change Zero with your Pc name hope you resolve your issue

Answer (score 1):

Here the quick way to solve the problem.You can add script command to package.json as below

```
"scripts": {
     ....
    "create":"ng g c components/auth-extensions"
  }
```

and run the command

```
npm run create
```

Once your job is done, you can delete the command from package.json.

This avoids installing global package, environment variable, path etc..

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have angular cli installed globally. This worked for me:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was encountered an error related to 'ng serve' it is opening the ng file. To resolve this issue, `you need to upgrade to a newer version of Node.js`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`
to the user variables in environment variable.
Then, close all your command window and then try again.