# not able to create angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

step1: `ng new myapp` 
step2: `cd myapp`
step3: `ng serve`
step4: open browser and enter "localhost:4200"
These are the steps for creating an angular application
After executing step 1, there's no application created 
Also when I try to get the version of angular using `ng --version`
I get this page in Visual Studio Code
[image]

I have installed nodejs too.
Kindly help me out

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50986835/angular-cli-ng-command-open-the-ng-file  if it helps
Also please clearly mention with screenshots for the behavior observed after each step

Comment: This is the result after 1st step. Once this becomes positive then only I would be able to proceed with the following steps. Thanks btw.